# How to pass var values from .js file to the variables in the bash file

Tags: node.js, bash, variables

I have a `variables.js` file that includes several variables with values like:

```
var var_1 = 1;
var var_2 = 'someText';
```

I need to pass these values to variables within the `vars` bash file:

```
VAR_1
VAR_2
```

That sounds like a decently simple task, however, having a lack of practical experience with bash scripts baffles me.

Tried using `source` or *reading line by line*, however, it didn't lead to a possible solution.

Comment: Are `var_1` and `var_2` the real variable names or are they placeholders for completely different names?

Comment: Just placeholders in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `grep` and a Perl-compatible regular expression (`-P`):

```
VAR_1=$(grep -Po '(?<=^var var_1 = ).*?(?=;)' variables.js)
VAR_2=$(grep -Po '(?<=^var var_2 = ).*?(?=;)' variables.js)
```

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858) -> Lookarounds